# Inserting paired input fields into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I need to insert pairs of input values from a form into mysql database. For example here are my input boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="roomType1" size="30" />       
<input type="text" name="roomRate1" size="30" />

<input type="text" name="roomType2" size="30" />       
<input type="text" name="roomRate2" size="30" />

<input type="text" name="roomType3" size="30" />       
<input type="text" name="roomRate3" size="30" />
```

etc..

And my sql database is set up as follows:

```
RoomType
RoomRate
HID
```

So basically I need to figure out how to pass the two input fields into each field together in the same row. I am not sure if I should do a for loop or how I can get each two and insert it with the same ID. I hope this makes sense. and any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Have u tried using any loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those inputs must be part of a form with method="post". Then, on the php side use this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while(isset($_POST['roomType'.$i]))
{
    $roomType = $_POST['roomType'$i];
    $roomRate = $_POST['roomRate'$i];

    // perform your sql statements here

    $i++;  
}
?>
```

Since your inputs are paired, it's enough to check if only one of them exists;

Comment: Thank you so much.. I thought it would be something like this just couldn't wrap my head around it.